# background job vs after_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a model called Vote that gets changed very frequently (people voting on stuff). I do other analytics after a vote is save, such as interpolating if the voter is male/female, what age etc. This results in updating counters in (adult votes, women votes etc) the same model.

I wonder what's the best way to do this after save processing, should this be a background job (I use delayed_job plugin) or should this be best left as an after_save callback? Which is better also from performance standpoint?

I don't really need to show upto the second latest data to the user (even the after_save callback doesn't accomplish that anyway).

Thanks

Comment: I would imagine that would depend on the mechanics of your analysis stuff? Is it a process where it analyzes an entire pool, in a way that would be cheaper to do en masse than one record at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My rule of thumb is that if it takes longer than a second (on average) to complete - I shove it to a background job, otherwise I will keep in synchronous.  I use [delayed job](http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), it works well and I have had no reason to leave it.  I had one case where I didn't need to hit the database in the background job and I used a custom rake task, it was very efficient and saved me having to implement a background job processor.

Comment: Second this approach with a further point:

If the task is non-critical to the usage of the application OR the user does not require this updated information immediately delayed_job it. 

e.g updating third party systems (invoicing perhaps) of a user name change does not impact on the users ability to use your application so use delayed_job